# TFS 2015 Reporting Service shows no data in Sprint Burndown

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-2015

I have configured TFS Reporting Service, I am using Scrum Template and TFS 2015.

While I try accessing Sprint Burndown, Release Burndown using Reporting Service WebURL - It is showing no data. Whereas if I try accessing Sprint Burndown from Sprint Board, it is showing data.

Below checks I have performed:

1. Iteration and sprints under that iteration are created
2. Start and End date for sprints are set
3. Users/team members are added and capacity is added

Can someone please assist me in what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Reporting in TFS makes use of Sql Server Analysis Server, or OLAP cube. This cube is by default refreshed every **two hours**.

Please follow the article below to do a manually refresh:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube

Also, you must select both Iteration and Area in Sprint Burndown.

[image]

Comment: 1) I followed link you suggested to manually refresh cube. And getting below error: -<Job JobProcessingStatus="Idle" Name="Incremental Analysis Database Sync">


-<LastRun Result="Failed" EndTimeUtc="2016-10-03T05:00:36.04Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2016-10-03T05:00:20.743Z" QueueTimeUtc="2016-10-03T05:00:20.073Z">

<ResultMessage>[Incremental Analysis Database Sync]: ---> AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType=Full, needCubeSchemaUpdate=True. --->

Comment: 2) Also, while executing burndown report, Itteration is selected but under Area, only available opton is "All (No Filter)" and there are not other Area being listed. I have created "TestScrumTemplate" area and User Story, Bugs are created under those areas only

Comment: It seems your report is not build successfully. Try to delete the Tfs_Analysis database and recreate it using TFS Admin Console.